# Error in background worker of vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

```
Dim isValidUser as Boolean   ' Global variable

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork( _
ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) _
Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork

    isValidUser = CheckInDataBase(Username,Pass)

End Sub  

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted( _
ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

       frmProcessing.Close()          

       If isValidUser then
             msgbox("Welcom")
       else 
             msgbox("Invalid Pswd")
       End IF
End Sub
```

In `RunWorkerCompleted` method `frmProcessing.close()` does not close the `frmProcessing` form at that point... It will close the `frmProcessing` after the respond to `msgbox`... why this happen... NOTE: `frmProcessing` is visibled as modal dialog... please help me

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are display a message over a form that is going to close so it will wait the messagebox to respond first and then it will close. If you want to close and generate a message box then you should do like this: (I am assuming from your requirement is that the Backgroundworker belongs to frmProcessing form)

FrmMain Code: (Assuming this is a owner form of `frmProcessing`)

```
Dim frmProcessing as new SomeProcessingFormName()

If (frmProcessing.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
      msgbox("Welcom")
   Else 
      msgbox("Invalid Pswd")
End If
```

FrmProcessing code:

```
Public isValidUser as Boolean ' Global variable OR make it a property

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork( _ ByVal sender As Object, _ ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) _ Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork

isValidUser = CheckInDataBase(Username,Pass)

End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

   frmProcessing.Close()          

   If isValidUser then
         Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok
   else 
         Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
   End If

End Sub
```